# BasicAuthentication not invoking my OnActionExecuting in Auth.cs - what may I have missed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have my controller decorated with: [BasicAuthentication] - however, putting in breakpoints, and stepping through the code, the [BasicAuthentication] never redirects to the Auth.cs (in the Filter folder):

Filter\Auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace ebapi.Filter
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
```

So the override OnActionExecuting never executes - but I cannot see what I've missed.  My controller, decorated with [BasicAuthentication] is shown below, but doesn't invoke my Auth.cs shown above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using ebapi.Filter;
using ebapi.Models;

namespace ebapi.Controllers
{
    public class GetBookingsController : ApiController
     {
        private GetBookingsContext db = new GetBookingsContext();
        private ApiMembersContext dba = new ApiMembersContext();

        // GET api/GetBookings/5
        [BasicAuthentication]
        public IEnumerable<GetBooking> GetBooking(long id)
        {
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Would the cache in the browsers maybe have anything to do with it?  If so, is there anyway to ensure it is rechecked on every Post/Get?

Answer (score 0):

if this helps, I changed the

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute name to: public class BasicAuthenticationV2Attribute
```

and changed the decoration to:

```
[BasicAuthenticationV2]
```

For whatever reason, this started the authentication again, and it fired with no problem.

I'm assuming there is some sort of caching going on, perhaps from the calling IP to the API - that means it remembers it's already authenticated someone, and doesn't need to again?

If anyone could confirm my thinking, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you,

Mark